# How to write a Linq query in this scenario

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to query MainObjList and invoke DoSomething() on ObjA only if ObjA ID1 and ID2 in ObjAList matches an ObJB ID1 and ID2 in ObjBList.

```
 public List<MainObj> MainObjList { get; set; }


 public class MainObj
    {
       public  List<ObjA> ObjAList { get; set; }

       public  List<ObjB> ObjBList { get; set; }

    }


    public class ObjA
    {
        public int ID1 { get; set; }
        public int ID2 { get; set; }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            //Do something Here
        }
    }

    public class ObjB
    {
        public int ID1 { get; set; }
        public int ID2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, can you show us what you've done so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Please show your real code - `ObjB` isn't used in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I had a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: @MegaTron I have no clue how to write this query. I tried using Any and ForEach but no luck at all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sami - "Please show your real code" - This means the real code you are trying to solve this problem for - not the fake `ObjA`/`ObjB` stuff in your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wish I can copy and paste the code. That would make it way easier. Company policy does not allow to post code, even when changing variable names. It is for "security purposes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to to join lists and combine them in one collection via `SelectMany`:

```
MainObjList.SelectMany(x => x.ObjAList.Join(x.ObjBList,
                        a => new { a.ID1, a.ID2 },
                        b => new { b.ID1, b.ID2 },
                        (a, b) => a))
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(x => x.DoSomething());
```

Comment: Your `public List<MainObj> MainObjList { get; set; }`

Comment: I like this one-liner, although for debugging purposes it is probably better to have the DoSomething() outside of the lambda.

Comment: @Cal279 I agree

Answer (score 1):

I believe the below should work, although having a nested `foreach` isn't ideal:

```
foreach (MainObj mainObj in MainObjList)
{
    IEnumerable<ObjA> objAMatches = mainObj.ObjAList
        .Join(mainObj.ObjBList, 
            objA => (objA.ID1, objA.ID2), 
            objB => (objB.ID1, objB.ID2), 
            (a, b) => a);

    foreach (ObjA objA in objAMatches)
    {
        objA.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `LINQ`-Expression.
You need to [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) your both entities and compare the IDs.

```
var mainObj = new MainObj(); //// Init your object and fill it with data

var equals = from objA in mainObj.ObjAList
        join objB in mainObj.ObjBList on new { objA.ID1, objA.ID2 } equals new { objB.ID1, objB.ID2 }
        select objA;

foreach(var entry in equals)
{
    entry.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MainObjectList should be a list.  See code below :

```
    public class Test
    {
        public MainObj MainObjList { get; set; }

        public Test()
        {
            var groups = from a in MainObjList.ObjAList
                         join b in MainObjList.ObjBList on a.ID1 equals b.ID1
                         where a.ID2 == b.ID2
                         select new { a = a, b = b };

        }

        public class MainObj
        {
           public  List<ObjA> ObjAList { get; set; }

           public  List<ObjB> ObjBList { get; set; }

        }


        public class ObjA
        {
            public int ID1 { get; set; }
            public int ID2 { get; set; }

            public void DoSomething()
            {
                //Do something Here
            }
        }

        public class ObjB
        {
            public int ID1 { get; set; }
            public int ID2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```cs
MainObjList.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.ObjAList.Where(a => x.ObjBList.Any(b => b.ID1 == a.ID1 && b.ID2 == a.ID2))
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(m => m.DoSomething());
});
```